# How to show multiple results in separate lines in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to return a single value when matching a set of queries against a list. Currently, the output looks something like this:

```
2 minute crafts out of paper for kids   {'paper'}
3d paper crafts for kids    {'paper'}
3d paper plane crafts for kids  {'paper'}
5 min crafts for kids with toilet paper {'paper', 'toilet'}
5 min crafts for kids with toilet paper rolls   {'paper', 'toilet'}
5 min paper crafts for kids {'paper'}
5 mins crafts for kids stuff you can do on a rainny day {'stuff'}
5 minute crafts christmas hot glue gun for kids {'glue'}
5 minute crafts for kids at home stuff  {'stuff'}
5 minute crafts for kids easter paintings   {'painting'}
```

What I would like is that when I have multiple matches, such as {'paper', 'toilet'}, they appear on separate lines, so it would be:

```
5 min crafts for kids with toilet paper {'paper'}
5 min crafts for kids with toilet paper {'toilet'}
```

This is my list:

```
category_to_keywords : {
'holidays' : ['wreath', 'diwali', 'new year', 'mothers', 'valentine', 
'halloween', 'christmas','patrick', 'thanksgiving', 'easter', '4th', 
'birthday', 'earth', 'fathers', 'fourth', 'holiday', 'ornament', 
'ramadan', 'snowman', 'turkey'],
'modifier' : ['beautiful', 'easy', 'diy', 'simple', 'fun', 'new', 
'printable', 'cool', 'modifier', 'best', 'free', 'good', 'home', 
'step', 'great', 'hacks', '3d'],
'season' : ['winter', 'spring', 'summer', 'fall', 'autumn'],
'subject' : ['waterfall', 'tree', 'glow', 'angel', 'ornament', 
'nest', 'coloring', 'handprint', 'mask', 'feeder', 'boat', 
'building', 'camping', 'dream', 'bracelet', 'jewelry', 'necklace', 
'clock', 'pillow', 'lily', 'space', 'bicycle', 'binoculars', 'bff', 
'bed', 'pine', 'popsicle', 'baking', 'banana', 'bank', 'barbie'],
'culture' : ['italian', 'japanese', 'mexican', 'indian', 'american', 
'african', 'china', 'egypt', 'arabic'],
'material' : ['cardboard', 'wreath', 'waste', 'plaster', 'plastic 
bag', 'plastic canvas', 'plastic', 'glow stick', 'stuff', 'egg', 
'flashlight', 'basket', 'bark', 'supplies', 'bean', 'bandana', 
'button', 'clay', 'coffee', 'construction', 'flip', 'glue', 'leaf', 
'painting', 'newspaper', 'paper', 'pine', 'popsicle', 'toilet', 
'wood', 'yarn'],
'time' : ['minute'],
'synonym' : ['gift', 'group', 'ideas', 'art', 'decoration', 
'activites', 'projects'],
'decade' : ['80s', '90s'],
'animal' : ['eagle', 'dog', 'cat ', 'zebra', 'firefly', 'fish', 
'shark', 'bird', 'bunny', 'butterfly', 'bug', 'caterpillar', 
'alien'],
'religious' : ['beatitudes', 'commandments', 'jesus', 'bible', 
'covenant', 'moses', 'joseph', 'advent ', 'catholic'],
'stories' : ['beatrix', 'storytime', 'seuss'],
'person' : ['benjamin franklin', 'abraham lincoln'],
'number' : ['100', '10'],
'sports' : ['basketball', 'football', 'baseball', 'tennis', 
'soccor'],
'food' : ['donut', 'ice cream', 'cookie', 'cake', 'strawberry', 
'recipes', 'food', 'pumpkin'],
'price' : ['cheap', 'buy', 'budget', 'inexpensive', 'sell'],
'day' : ['rainy', 'sunny', 'snowy'],
'audience' : ['kids', 'parents', 'grandparents'],
'age' : ['old', 'young', 'preschool', 'age', 'little'],
'month' : ['august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december', 
'january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july'],
'social' : ['pinterest', 'facebook', 'tik tok'],
'learning' : ['american history', '9 11', 'ecosystem', 'science', 
'solar system'],
'brand' : ['martha stewart', 'walmart', 'michaels', 'home depot'],
'location' : ['outdoor', 'indoor'],
'theme' : ['beach', 'space', 'animal'],
}
```

And then my function:

```
def find_matching_keywords_with_categories(query, 
category_to_keywords):
    unfiltered_result = {
        category: find_matching_keywords(query, keywords)
        for category, keywords
        in category_to_keywords.items()
    }
    return {
        category: keywords
        for (category, keywords)
        in unfiltered_result.items()
        if keywords
    }

query_to_keywords = {
    query: find_matching_keywords_with_categories(query.lower(), 
category_to_keywords)
    for query in query_list
}

for query, keywords in query_to_keywords.items():
    print(query, keywords)
```

is there a way I can do this?

Comment: You'll need to provide some code if you want advice on how to change the code.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I updated the question with code.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the last loop:

```
for query, keywords in query_to_keywords.items():
    print(query, keywords)
```

to:

```
for query, categories in query_to_keywords.items():
    for keywords in categories.values():
        for keyword in keywords:
            print(query, keyword)
```

Comment: That didn't work. Here is the output: easy crafts for kids with glue audience. The output should be the matching keyword, not the category.

Comment: Ah, `keywords` is actually a dict of `{category: keywords}` -- in your OP and based on the variable naming it looked like it was a set of keywords.  I think that means you want to iterate over its `values` in a nested loop then.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, that does work! But the csv export is in the same format.

Comment: What CSV export?

Comment: This is how I set up the CSV export - df2 = pd.DataFrame(query_to_keywords)
df2_transposed = df2.T then df2_transposed.to_csv("youtube_us_crafts-for-kids_final.csv")

Comment: Don't pass `query_to_keywords` to your CSV export; it's in the wrong format for what you want.  What I think you want to export is `[(query, keyword) for query, categories in query_to_keywords.items() for keywords in categories.values() for keyword in keywords]`.

Comment: Yes! It's getting closer, but what I really want to export is one value per category, not just one value overall.

Comment: I updated it to [(query, categories, keyword) for query, categories in query_to_keywords.items() for keywords in categories.values() for keyword in keywords] so we can reference the category. Thank you so much for the help!